# Express Server Printing ^@ Periodically

Tags: node.js, express

This is happening across all express servers running on my RMBP Yosemite.

Here is a sample output, where I used the official generator to produce a dummy project, and left it running for a while:

```
> express_test@0.0.0 start /Users/myou/code/express_test
> node ./bin/www

GET / 200 281.984 ms - 170
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 4.483 ms - 111
GET /favicon.ico 404 19.569 ms - 1105
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

Notice all the ^@ that were being printed every couple of minutes.

Any ideas?

Max

Comment: it look like keyboard problem or any software send key code

Comment: @trquoccuong care to elaborate a bit further? do you mean process is running that's sending key press events to my terminal?

Comment: Odd...double check your not logging it out somewhere in your project. Other than that I'm not sure

Comment: Yes, I think any process send keypress

Comment: @James111 don't think that's possible since I'm running default generator dummy projects; and the same thing happens with all projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...I solved the problem...it's pretty stupid actually.

In iterm2 there's a setting to send keystrokes to idle processes, probably to prevent SSH sessions from timing out and such. And the default key stroke is ^@.